# QT Network QObject::connect no matching member function

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I am new to QT and maybe i just dont see something. but QObject::connect method gives me this error -> **no matching member function for call to 'connect'**.

I googled and searched but nothing helps. Actually even examples from official documentation give me the same error. All libraries are imported.

**QTCreator version is 4.14
Based on Qt5.15**

Here is a sample of my code

```
#include "imagepagehandler.h"
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QIODevice>

ImagePageHandler::ImagePageHandler(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    networkAccessManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
    networkReply = nullptr;
    dataBuffer = new QByteArray();

    QNetworkRequest request;
    request.setUrl(QUrl("https://www.qt.io"));

    networkReply = networkAccessManager->get(request);

   connect(networkReply, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &ImagePageHandler::DataReadyToRead);

}

void ImagePageHandler::DataReadyToRead()
{

}

void ImagePageHandler::DataReadFinished()
{

}
```

And header

```
#define IMAGEPAGEHANDLER_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

class ImagePageHandler : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ImagePageHandler(QObject *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void DataReadyToRead();
    void DataReadFinished();

private:
    QNetworkAccessManager* networkAccessManager;
    QNetworkReply* networkReply;
    QByteArray* dataBuffer;


signals:

};

#endif // IMAGEPAGEHANDLER_H
```

Issues screenshot

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the header file? Is there the Q_OBJECT macro defined?

Comment: @bzs Hello. Sorry didnt provided it earlier. Edited the post and added.  Yeah seems that macro is there. Thats one of the things i checked before.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete error message(s) verbatim.  Do you have `using namespace std;` anywhere?

Comment: @G.M. I included a screenshot. Not i dont have namespace std anywhere. Also the project is basically blank.

Comment: Please show the error messages as text instead of posting images.  Having said that, the error is that `QNetworkReply` is only forward declared.  Add `#include <QNetworkReply>` in your source file.

Comment: incomplete type QNetworkReply: add in cpp: #include <QNetworkReply>

Comment: @G.M. So stupid. It was the issue indeed. Thanks a lot. Since im not rly c++ experienced user. Why it even allows me to use QNetworkReply if i did not include it? Thanks again.